Can Anyone help with understanding the hardhat environment?
Ethereum Smart Contract Deployment Issue
Context
I'm new to blockchain development and currently following the FreeCodeCamp tutorial by Patrick Collins. While I have a basic understanding of Solidity and Ethers.js, I'm encountering issues connecting to the Alchemy Sepolia testnet.
Structure of the project

Code Implementation
Deployment Script
import pkg from 'hardhat';
const { ethers, network, run } = pkg;
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify";

const main = async () => {
    // Get the contract factory
    const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");
    console.log("Deploying smart contract...");

    // Deploy the contract
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy();
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment();

    const contractAddress = await simpleStorage.getAddress();
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", contractAddress);
    console.log("Network id:", network.config.chainId);

    // Verify contract on Sepolia testnet if Etherscan API key is available
    if (network.config.chainId === 31337) {
        console.log("Waiting for 6 block confirmations...");
        await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction().wait(6);
        await verify(contractAddress, []);
    }
    
    // Test contract functionality
    const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
    console.log(`Current value is: ${currentValue}`);

    const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store("8");
    await transactionResponse.wait(1);

    const updatedValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
    console.log(`Updated value is: ${updatedValue}`);
};

Hardhat Configuration
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('dotenv').config();

const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
        }
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
    },
    sourcify: {
        enabled: true
    },
    solidity: "0.8.27",
};

Questions

Could someone explain the overall project structure?
What might be causing the connection issues with the Alchemy Sepolia chain?


What’s the exact error that you’re encountering?

When using a smart contract development framework, such as Hardhat, there are a few different common pieces.

Smart contracts - Usually a folder in your project's root containing all of
the smart contracts related to the project.

In Hardhat it's your contracts folder.
In Foundry it's your src folder.


Tests - Also a folder in the root of your project, this contains all of your files used to test the smart contract logic and ensure it behaves as expected.

In Hardhat it's your test folder.
In Foundry it's your test folder.


Deploy scripts - Another folder in the same location, this contains all your files used to deploy smart contracts to the blockchain specified in the config/script.

In Hardhat there are a few different options for deploying your contracts.

You can use Hardhat
Ignition
with an ignition folder, like you are currently doing.
You can use Hardhat Viem or Hardhat Ethers with a script folder.
You can use hardhat-deploy with a deploy folder.


In Foundry it's your script folder.


Config - A single file allowing you to set project-wide configurations to fit your desired needs, e.g. adding the chainId for Sepolia testnet.

In Hardhat it's your hardhat.config.js file.
In Foundry it's your foundry.toml file.



Another piece included in your screenshot is a tasks folder, tasks in hardhat are useful for creating certain utility scripts. You could choose to write them directly inside your hardhat.config file, but using a tasks folder is a good way to keep your code organized, especially when writing large or complex scripts.
Here is an image from the Hardhat documentation showing an example of what a default project structure might look like:

Here is the corresponding image from the Foundry documentation:

Both are fairly similar with their naming conventions even being identical on a couple of occasions. If you want to read more about setting up a project, or project structure in general, with either one of these frameworks, you can see this Hardhat page and this Foundry page.
To answer your second question, it could be because you aren't referencing the Sepolia network when you run your deploy script with a --network sepolia tag, or it could be because your code is only set to verify the contract when the network.config.chainId variable is set to 31337, which is the hardhat local blockchain's chainId, not Sepolia. Try changing this:
 // Verify contract on Sepolia testnet if Etherscan API key is available
    if (network.config.chainId === 31337) {
        console.log("Waiting for 6 block confirmations...");

To this:
 // Verify contract on Sepolia testnet if Etherscan API key is available
    if (network.config.chainId === 11155111) {
        console.log("Waiting for 6 block confirmations...");

That is only a possibility of being the issue you are having, so if you can, provide the exact error message you are getting and the exact command you are trying to run.
